# sysdate, single or multiple values?

Tags: oracle

If you run this query, and the results take 3 minutes to generate.........

```
select to_char((sysdate),'dd_mm_yyyy___HH24_MI_SS') as MyStamp , e.* from EMP e;
```

Will the value for MyStamp be one single value, or 180 (60 seconds x 3 minutes) ?

I've tested it, and it looks like a single value.

But I'm trying to figure out if there is some snap-fu that I cannot rely on it.

I checked the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

and it didn't say anything there.

Comment: 1. you don't need the brackets around `(sysdate)` and 2. if it takes a long time to run, try to see the "plan" and I would also just run `select * from EMP` and see if that takes long to run as well.

Comment: I'm not worried about performance.  I'm concerned about whether the value is static or not.  But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value returned by SYSDATE is constant within a single statement.  There are some subtleties to this which David explains in his answer.

Obviously it would be better if the documentation explicitly said this.

Comment: Is a NEXTVAL constant within a single statement? For e.g., http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b98d/1

Comment: NEXTVAL/CURRVAL is constant within a single row. If the select returns more than one row, NEXTVAL/CURRVAL will change for each row.

Comment: @Ben - you're quite right.  What I meant was what Jeffrey said.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed466/2    With hindsight, the mention of sequences obscures rather than illuminates, so I have removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to APC's correct answer, one quirk worth noting is that SQL executed within a function call as part of another SQL statement gets a new consistency point, including that for sysdate, so sysdate within a function call can be different to sysdate in the parent query.

So if you have a function call in your query that uses sysdate ...

```
select ...
from   large_table
where  some_complex_relative_time_function(large_table.datetime_of_activity) < sysdate;
```

... it's safer to pass your value of sysdate into it:

```
select ...
from   large_table
where  some_complex_relative_time_function(large_table.datetime_of_activity, sysdate) < sysdate;
```